# Need Multiple value in dropdown list and combine two value from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to combine two column in drop-down list and need result from sql.i have already try with putting space between two value but not get proper alignment.

i need result like below.

```
TRAVEL      |     Travel Rate
PAINT       |     PAINT
MOTEL       |     Motel Rate
Labor1      |     Mobilization Labor
```

i try with following query.

```
 SELECT ItemID  + SPACE(12 - len(ItemID)) + '|'  + Description
FROM InventoryMaster
```

but get this result

```
TRAVEL      |Travel Rate
PAINT     |PAINT
MOTEL       |Motel Rate
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this usage of RIGHT & LEFT padding:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501038/right-pad-a-string-with-variable-number-of-spaces

Answer (score 0):

As @RST_7 wrote:

```
SELECT LEFT (ItemID + SPACE (12), 12) + '|     '  + Description
FROM InventoryMaster
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the font you use in the UI. try to use fixed-width