# Something wrong in Preprending string with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on the suggestion in this post [Right pad a string with variable number of spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501038/right-pad-a-string-with-variable-number-of-spaces/12501455)

For testing purposes, I created a table and added the following rows

```
CREATE TABLE CharTest (
  ID int,
  CharField char(6) NULL
);

INSERT INTO CharTest
VALUES (1, '    90');

INSERT INTO CharTest
VALUES (1, '    89');

INSERT INTO CharTest
VALUES (1, NULL);

INSERT INTO CharTest
VALUES (1, '    91');

INSERT INTO CharTest
VALUES (1, '    90');
```

I then tried executing this query

```
DECLARE @lCharField char(6)
SET @lCharField = '90'

SELECT CharField FROM CharTest
where CharField = RIGHT(space(6) + @lCharField, 6)
```

it returned no rows.

I checked the output of the following queries

```
SELECT RIGHT(space(6) + @lCharField, 6) FROM CharTest
SELECT RIGHT('      ' + @lCharField, 6) FROM CharTest
```

and it doesn't seem to right-pad or pre-prend the spaces as expected.

Any help in pointing out what I am doing wrong is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_space.asp  SPACE adds them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this code:

```
DECLARE @lCharField char(6);
SET @lCharField = '90';
```

You *think* the result is `'90'` but it is really `'90      '`.  That throws everything off.  Use:

```
DECLARE @lCharField varchar(6);
SET @lCharField = '90';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56ffec9f3be81bc2c660ad1f3d17bf4f) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that finicky spaces are one important reason why `varchar()` is used -- say -- 100 times more often than `char()`.  The only really good use for `char()` is for columns that are of *fixed* width, such as ISO3 code for counties.